# How to examine internal Windows 10 PC drive(s) while PC is off

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, laptop

I'd like to know how to access an internal drive on a Windows 10 PC while the PC or laptop is off, assuming this is possible

Comment: Define "access" please.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without removing the drive & mounting to another computer (only useful if you specifically do not want to power up the computer the drive is in.)

Without electricity, it's a doorstop.